# Why does my internal hyperlink not work in pug?

Tags: pug

I am working on a personal blog that has multiple sections on the same page and I would like to navigate to the different sections by linking them at the top with an anchor tag.

The URL changes in the address bar when I click the link but I'm not able to navigate to the correct section with the id. Here's the code structure.

```
extends /_includes/layout

block title
    title 

block content

    .cb-layout#view-main
        .cb-content
            .cb-tabs.-inverse
                .cb-tabs-navs
                    h3 
                        a(href="#about") ABOUT
                    h3
                        a(href="#projects") PROJECTS
                    h3
                        a(href="#contributions") CONTRIBUTIONS
                    h3
                        a(href="#social") SOCIAL
                    
                    //- .cb-tabs-nav.-active
                    //- .cb-tabs-nav
                    //- .cb-tabs-nav
                
            section.cb-outro#about
                .cb-outro-content
                    .cb-outro-container
                        .cb-outro-header
                            h2 About
                        .cb-outro-list
                            
            
            section.cb-outro#areas-of-interest
                .cb-outro-content
                    .cb-outro-container
                        .cb-outro-header
                            h2 Areas of Interest

                        .cb-outro-list
                            

            section.cb-outro#currently-learning
                .cb-outro-content
                    .cb-outro-container
                        .cb-outro-header
                            h2 Currently Learning

                        .cb-outro-list
                            
                        

            section.cb-outro#projects
                .cb-outro-content
                    .cb-outro-container
                        .cb-outro-header
                            h2 Projects
                        .cb-outro-list

            section.cb-outro#contributions
                .cb-outro-content
                    .cb-outro-container
                        .cb-outro-header
                            h2 Open Source Contributions
                        .cb-outro-list
                            
                            
            section.cb-outro#social
                .cb-outro-content
                    .cb-outro-container
                        .cb-outro-header
                            h2 Social
                        .cb-outro-list
```

I'm new to pug and can someone tell me what's wrong? I've been trying to fix this for so long and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the compiled HTML and CSS in a [mcve].

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the example you provide